# Can we do RTMP Streaming in ios app?

Tags: ios, iphone, streaming, rtmp

Can we do RTMP Streaming in ios app?

I have stream from cross devices using RTMP without delay or latency. I have tried HLS but its has more latency.

So please suggest, I can ready to buy the code or library, if it'll match my scenarios.

Comment: Hey, Have you able to crack it? Which player or library are you using it to play rtmp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, Yes. But apple will reject it from the app store if the content is longer that 10 minutes and uses cellular data.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1767/_index.html

Update: 
It appears that apple does allow some apps to break this rule now. But YMMV

Comment: Hi, Could you suggest any library which will help me to play rtmp url?

Comment: Try MobileVLCKit library @Yohan